Where can I get refined metal?
I need refined metal for an upgrade in Dredge but I haven't been able to find any. How do I get refined metal?

The easiest way to get Refined Metal is to buy it. The traveling merchant who’s set up shop at each of the four archipelagos sells it for $500 a pop. She’s got limited supply, however, so you’ll only get one per pontoon before she needs to restock.
If you don't want to buy it, each of the archipelagos has at least one area where you’ll find Refined Metal. The majority of them are blocked by debris, meaning you need Packed Explosives.
The easiest spots where to find Refine metal are:

Gale Cliffs: sail into the open area and locate the waterfall. Go through the waterfall, where you’ll find a chest with Refined Materials and other goodies.
Stellar Basin: to the west of the most western island’s southern tip there’s a floating treasure chest with Refined Metal.

Source, here.
